# 'ascii' codec can't encode character x

Tags: python-2.7, csv, character-encoding, decoding

I am trying to write some special characters to .csv file. My code is here:

```
fp = open(csv_file, 'w')
test = []
test.append(unicode('òHeyàù', 'utf-8'))
fp.write('\t'.join(test[0].encode('UTF-8')))
fp.write('\n')
```

This is the output:

> Ã²HeyÃÃ¹

which I guess should be decoded. So then I wrote this:

```
test = []
test.append('òHeyàù'.encode('utf-8'))
fp.write('\t'.join(test[0].decode('UTF-8')))
fp.write('\n')
```

which the following error apperes:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position
>   0: ordinal not in range(128)

How should I write specific characters to a CSV file?

**EDIT:**
I tried to convert string to ascii, howeve still doesn't work properly:

```
test = [] 
test.append(unicode('òHeyàù', 'utf-8'))
testtest = test[0].encode('UTF-8') 
swriter = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL) 
swriter.writerow([ord(c) for c in testtest]) # converting string to ascii however it prints a list of numbers
```

Comment: Why the `decide` in the last write? You are writing, so you need to encode.In any case you are using a string (not an unicode string), because of `'\t'` being a string. Keep string ASCII (so without accent).  Better:use python3, which corrected (instead of adding hack) the string coding/decoding).

Comment: post has been edited

Comment: You've already indicated requirements that make using ASCII impossible.